# Change the title of Paypal PaymentActivity class

Tags: android, paypal

I included paypal sdk in the app and set the product name and price as shown in the attached image.

Is it possible to change the title of the paypal PaymentActivity class . ?

I used the entire code for paypal from this [link](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) 
.Please suggest whether we could change the title to any text ,(I want to change the text that is marked in Red Circle)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Jeff here from the PayPal Mobile SDK team.

The PayPal Android SDK doesn't support modifying any of the SDK activities.  We don't plan to allow the ability to modify titles, as this would be an inconsistent user experience.  However, we're open to feedback from users, so please feel free to file issues in [GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) if you have feature requests!

Comment: Hi Jeff, So according to your answer we can't modify the any pages right? I need to modify theme & also some customisation. Its not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your `AndroidManifest.xml` file should have an entry for the `PaymentActivity` that looks like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity" />
```

All you should have to do is add the [`label` attribute](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#label) to that to change the title:

```
<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity" android:label="@string/some_title" />
```

For other potentially useful attributes, refer to the [`activity` tag documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

Note: I'm assuming here that the PayPal SDK will allow you to override the title. That is, I would expect it to only set a default title if none is given explicitly.

---

**Edit**: Unfortunately, the assumption above has proven to be incorrect. Diving a little deeper, it turns out every activity in the PayPal SDK always sets its title in the `onCreate()` method. That's actually a little surprising, because that means that PayPal isn't leveraging Android's built-in support for localisation and resources. Although I suppose it does allow them to offer developers the SDK as a jar, which doesn't support bundling Android resources.

In any case, since the various activities haven't been declared `final`, you could simply try to extend them and set the title after the super has done its work:

```
public class TitlePaymentMethodActivity extends PaymentMethodActivity {

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Custom Title")
        // or:
        setTitle(R.string.custom_title);
    }

}
```

After that, you'll have to change the manifest to point to your `TitlePaymentMethodActivity`, in stead of directly to the activity in the SDK. Do note that this approach may break at any point, if PayPal decides to finalize the activity classes. With that in mind, I suggest you follow @shoe rat's recommendation and file a request with PayPal for 'official' support.

Comment: Thank you  for your valuable suggestion , But unfortunately its not working  ...Why is this?

Comment: Probably, because PayPal SDK does not support it

Comment: @user2495758: It seems PayPal explicitly sets the title whenever the activity is created. I've updated my answer with an alternative approach, but this could be a lot easier if PayPal would officially support this feature. That's why it may not be a bad idea to file a request, even if above answers your question.

Comment: @MH., I tried extending `PaymentActivity` and `PaymentMethodActivity` before posting the answer, but could not make it work for lack of documentation (as posted there). The payment process fails without any meaningful errors and logs.

Answer (score 0):

Couple observations, apparently:

- The activity of off which you have put screenshot is `PaymentMethodActivity` (according to Hierarchy Viewer)
- PayPal SDK uses [ABS](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock)

According to the sample app provided in PayPal SDK page, [`onBuyPressed()`](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/SampleApp/src/com/paypal/example/paypalandroidsdkexample/MainActivity.java#L44) launches PaymentActivity with `startActivityForResult()`:

**Now, according to [SDK references](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-Android-SDK/com/paypal/android/sdk/payments/PaymentActivity.html), PaymentActivity does not provide any API for setting custom title. The page lists `setTitle()` as a part of "Methods inherited from class android.app.Activity", but does not give any details on how to extend PaymentActivity so that one could leverage those APIs.**

So, currently, there is no way to use a custom title.

I personally would not bother to change the title on that screen as it clearly depicts itself as a PayPal screen (as one would see their homepage on a browser), but if you really want a custom title, you may need to [file a new issue on their GitHub page](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues).